# What is the best mysql type to storage hash values

Tags: mysql

There are few data Types in MySQL, so I was wondering what is the best data type for storing hash values like RIPEMD-160.

I now that I could use a Text type but I only want to storage the space that hash algorithms need.

So, what are my alternatives?

Comment: If its always going to be of same length? You cold have say `CHAR(20)`

Comment: A `BINARY(20)` would be enough to store the raw hash output of 160 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RIPEMD-160 transforms the string in a 160bit hash you can just use **CHAR(40)** (If you transform it in hex you'll be able to represent it in 40 char), otherwise, if you ever find yourself with a variable-lenght hashing algorithm, you can use **VARCHAR**, which will only occupy the space you need (with a little overhead).

For more info: [**mysql's reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on WHAT are you going to store, which means you have to answer yourself, what hash function are you going to use?

For RIPEMD-160, it always returns a 40byte string representing an hexadecimal number, so i would go with char(40).

Using char when the length is always the same provides a minor speed increase.